# Similar UITapGestureRecognizer Actions for Many ImageView

Tags: swift, xcode

I am relatively new to Swift.

I have many images (though right now I am testing with four) which I am trying to hide (temporarily to make sure the foundational code is working, instead I really want to insert an image under the tapped image) when they are tapped.

I have created an `array` of `ImageViews` which I plan to expand once I have working code. I tried to add `UITapGestureRecognizers` to each `ImageView` using a for loop in `addGestures()` and then have `selectImage()` hide the tapped `ImageView`. The code compiles without error, but fails with `uncaught NSException` when one of these images is tapped. Any tips on how to do this effectively without too much manual coding for each image?

[Code attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPjrb.png)

Comment: i think you can get imageview baby it's property "view" , like your tapGesture.view.

Comment: Add code in the question instead of Image

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to embed the image but the link at the bottom should work

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code

```
func addGestureRecognizer(){
    for imageView in imageArray{
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(gesture:)))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
}

@objc func handleTap(gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let imageView = gesture.view
    imageView?.isHidden = true
}
```

in your code you're passing imageView instead of gesture on selector.however you can get imageView by gesture.view.

Also there is no need for separate function for enable userInteraction.

Comment: Great Answer! The only thing I needed to change is: func addGestureRecognizer(imageArray: [UIImageView]) and then called it in viewDidLoad() by addGestureRecognizer(imageArray: imageArray) and then it worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: yes! but if your array is global then there is no need to do that! Also you can prepare your array just before for loop

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can try

```
class GestureStackVC: UIViewController {

    /// Image Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var img1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var img2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var img3: UIImageView!

    /// ImageView Array
    var imagesArray : [UIImageView]?

    /// Image Gesture
    var imageTapGesture : UITapGestureRecognizer?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        /// Allocate Array
        imagesArray = [UIImageView]()

        /// Add Required Values
        imagesArray = [img1,img2,img3]

        /// Add gesture
        for imageView in imagesArray!{
            let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapHandler(_:)))
            imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        }
    }

    /// tap Handler
    @objc func imageTapHandler(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        /// Hide the Sender View
        sender.view?.isHidden = true
        /// Done
    }
}
```

**First Output with 3 Images**

[image]

**Output when clicked On first ImageView1 - Results its hidden**
[image]

**Output when clicked On first ImageView2 - Results its hidden**
[image]